# Parse Column in R - Removing Delimitor

Tags: r, gsub

I have a dataset like below:

```
Col2      Col4    Col5     Col6
  A     dfjk::      6         9
  B     DJE|end    92       133
  C     nedl5      13        12
```

How do I parse out the 2nd column by the delimitor `|`?

Final Expected output:

```
Col2      Col4    NEW    Col5     Col6
  A     dfjk::     NA       6         9
  B        DJE    end      92       133
  C     nedl5      NA      13        12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `tidyr::separate`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% separate(Col4, c("Col4", "NEW"), sep = "\\|", fill = "right")
#  Col2   Col4  NEW Col5 Col6
#1    A dfjk:: <NA>    6    9
#2    B    DJE  end   92  133
#3    C  nedl5 <NA>   13   12
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
"Col2      Col4    Col5     Col6
  A     dfjk::      6         9
  B     DJE|end    92       133
  C     nedl5      13        12", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

A quite handy possibility is using `cSplit()` from `splitstackshape`:

```
cSplit(df, "Col4", "|")

   Col2 Col5 Col6 Col4_1 Col4_2
1:    A    6    9 dfjk::   <NA>
2:    B   92  133    DJE    end
3:    C   13   12  nedl5   <NA>
```